# Creating a bare repository on a Git server remotely

Tags: git, ssh

Is there any way to create bare repositories on a Git server remotely from my local machine?

I'm trying to eliminate the annoyance of having to ssh in to my Git server and create the bare repo manually.

It's probably not possible, but ideally I'd like to create local git repositories, and push them straight away to my Git server without having to create bare versions on the server first.

Am I asking too much of Git?

Comment: I think ssh is the best way `ssh remoteserver 'cd $PATH; git init'`

Comment: @Biffen what about `$ ssh remoteserver 'cd YOURPATH;mkdir REPONAME; cd REPONAME; git init'
`

Comment: @bigOTHER, @Biffen `git init <dirname>` creates and initialize the repo in one step

Comment: @joran the `--bare` option is good for this case ,thank you for pointing to it

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I think the best way is through ssh, something like:

```
$ ssh remoteserver 'git init --bare YOURPATH/REPONAME'
```

You can configure to use [SSH as password-less](http://www.linuxproblem.org/art_9.html) if you are going to use it lot of times.

Comment: No need to create dir, or change dir, prior a init,  you can shorten this to `ssh remoteserver 'git init ---bare YOURPATH/REPONAME` (I think you forgot the `--bare` option)

Comment: I am here to emphasize "use SSH as password-less" in this fine answer. Life is too short not to use public-key authentication.

Comment: The ssh command is identical to what I was doing before, but I didn't know you could just send ssh commands to a server and close the connection in one line. This reduces time significantly. Thanks.