# Creating Master Repository on Ubuntu server?

Tags: windows, git, ubuntu

I am new to `Git` ,I want to create a repository on my Ubuntu Server that is hosted on AWS.

I want this to be the `master repository`for my live website, but I will keep my local repository on my `Windows` computer.

How do I do this?

Comment: What have you tried? https://git-scm.com/book/it/v2/Git-Basics-Getting-a-Git-Repository https://www.atlassian.com/git/tutorials/setting-up-a-repository/git-init

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Creating a bare repository on a Git server remotely](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32298621/creating-a-bare-repository-on-a-git-server-remotely) and a host of other answers on SO.